# Converting String to Int in Swift

Tags: swift

Hello I'm new to Swift and I'm building a calculator in Xcode. In my main storyboard I have a `UIButton`, `UILabel` and a `UITextField` that will get a number and by pressing the button, label's text should show the entered number + 5. In my app I need to convert a `String` variable to `Int`.

I tried the snippet below I didn't get any meaningful result.

```
var e = texti.text
let f: Int? = e.toInt()
let kashk = f * 2
label.text = "\(pashm)"
```

Comment: Where is `pashm` defined? Are you trying to convert `+5` to an Int?

Comment: " I tried the codes to convert but I didn't get any answer." What does _that_ mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make it clean and *Swifty*, I suggest this approach:

#### Swift 2 / 3

```
var string = "42" // here you would put your 'texti.text', assuming texti is for example UILabel

if let intVersion = Int(string) { // Swift 1.2: string.toInt()
    let multiplied = 2 * intVersion
    let multipliedString = "\(multiplied)"
    // use the string as you wish, for example 'texti.text = multipliedString'
} else {
    // handle the fact, that toInt() didn't yield an integer value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to calculate with that new integer you have to unwrap it by putting an exclamation mark behind the variable name:

```
let stringnumber = "12"
let intnumber:Int? = Int(stringnumber)

print(intnumber!+3)
```

The result would be:

```
15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "12"
var intVersion = string.toInt()
let intMultipied = intVersion! * 2
label.text= "\(intMultipied)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding how to convert a string to a integer:

```
var myString = "12" //Assign the value of your textfield
if let myInt = myString.toInt(){
    //myInt is a integer with the value of "12"
} else {
    //Do something, the text in the textfield is not a integer
}
```

The `if let` makes sure that your value can be casted to a integer.
`.toInt()` returns an optional Integer. If your string can be casted to a integer it will be, else it will return `nil`. The `if let` statement will only be casted if your string can be casted to a integer.

Since the new variable (constant to be exact) is a integer, you can make a new variable and add 5 to the value of your integer

```
var myString = "12" //Assign the value of your textfield
if let myInt = myString.toInt(){
    //myInt is a integer with the value of “12”
    let newInt = myInt + 5

    myTextfield.text = "\(newInt)"
    //The text of the textfield will be: "17" (12 + 5)
} else {
    //Do something, the text in the textfield is not a integer
}
```

Comment: I seriously should stop answering when i’m not behind my mac using xCode, thanks @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: I’ve we’re gonna play it that way, why not use `myTextfield.text = “\(myInt + 5)”` and make no new constant at all?

Comment: Question was pretty “basic” better wright it out I think since I suspect OP is new to swift