# Optional issue converting String to Int in Swift 1.2

Tags: swift

I can't figure out why this 'optional' isn't working in scenario 1, but without the optional ? it works in scenario 2.

Using Swift v 1.2, xCode 6.2

```
var stuff = "6t"

// SCENARIO 1
// Why is this failing when stuff contains non-digit characters?
// i.e. it works if stuff = "45".
if let value: Int? = stuff.toInt() {
    println("value \(value!)")
}

// SCENARIO 2    
// This works!
if let value = stuff.toInt() {
    println("val3 \(value)")
}
```

For Reference also see these SO Answers:
* I wonder if the Sift 1.2 example/Answer here is just plain wrong?
[Swift - Converting String to Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115141/swift-converting-string-to-int/24183839#comment63735977_24183839)

[Converting String to Int in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101873/converting-string-to-int-in-swift)

Comment: `if let value: Int?` makes no sense — the whole point of `if let` is to unwrap an optional

Comment: Why would anyone be using Swift 2.1? Swift 2 has been out for ages, and Swift 3 is here already!

Comment: Swift 1.2 @matt - because I can't upgrade xCode without upgrading my OS which will mess up my ProTools installation.

Comment: The way I solve that is with an external Thunderbolt SSD. I've installed El Capitan on that, along with Xcode 7 and Xcode 8. I boot off that when I want to do Xcode. Meanwhile, back on the internal drive, the old system is still there. Come on, you need to take a little responsibility for what version of Swift you're using!

Comment: Believe me, it's on my todo list, was hoping to run new OS X in a virtual machine. I use ThunderBolt output for my 2nd monitor, could use USB, but prefer VM if it performs OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The first IF is always true.

Infact in both cases:

1. when the `toInt()` returns a valid `Int`
2. when returns `nil`

the `if let` will succeed (and yes, the first IF is useless).

Specifically in your code `toInt()` returns `nil` in both scenarios.
But in your first scenario you are simply accepting `nil` as a valid value to enter the THEN block.

Comment: I'm still confused. Are you saying this expression is true: `if let value: Int? = nil`

Comment: In a Playground this evaluates to `nil`, so I would of thought the if statement would fail:
`
var stuff = "6r"

let value: Int? = stuff.toInt()
`

Comment: Now I see what `let` does. This works because it's declaring the optional before the `let`: `var result: Int? = stuff.toInt()

if let value = result {
    println("value \(value)")
}`

Comment: @GiantElk: exactly. Since `value` is declared as `Int?` and `toInt()` always returns an `Int?` (sometimes an `Int` sometimes a  `nil`), the assignment will always succeed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point of using `if let value: Int?`. If the `if let` works, then the value is an `Int`. There is no way that it could be nil. Therefore, you do not need to declare it as an optional.